# OpenSearch Data Table how can I split a field Value?

Tags: datatable, opensearch

I try to create a Dashboard in OpenSearch. There I have a data table which I fill with data. Now I got a row called Message which looks like that:

"Job Success. job_id=value, dataB = valueB, ...."

I can't access dataB directly, so I wanted to gather it from the message. Is there a way to split the text or cut out this text?

I tried advanced settings and looked for examples for JSON input but I didn't find something I could use. I only have access of the visualize and not more experience about OpenSearch.

Edit: While i was looking over it I noticed that dataB is "unkown field" in the "Discover" view

Comment: did you try the devtools? https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/dev-tools/run-queries/

Comment: No, i take a look. I am new to opensearch. I don t know how to use it.